# WSO2 Identity Server: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-identity-server

I just got started with WSO2 Identity Server-6.1.0, JAVA is already set as I use WSO2-EI and trying the Sample applications given in the Documentation.
I've reached at this step- [Sample Applications for WSO2 Identity Server](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/get-started/sample-use-cases/sample-scenario/#set-up-the-sample-apps)

But I continuously get the below errors when I start the app-server using the command. Is there any other dependency I need to download?

```
api-server.bat
```

.

[image]

[image]